# `knitr::include_url` ignored in output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

After updating R to version 3.6.0, and re-installing the required packages, knitting **Rmd** documents now seems to ignore the `knitr::include_url` function.

The following is a minimal example, in a file named `test.Rmd` -

````
---
title: "test"
author: "Michael Dorman"
date: "May 1, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
knitr::include_url("https://www.wikipedia.org/")
```

```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2.png")
```
````

And here is a screenshot of the output, after pressing **Knit** in Rstudio -

[image]

The `knitr::include_url` function is ignored. No `<iframe>` element was produced. The `knitr::include_graphics` function still works, so the image does appear in the output.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Sounds like this bug https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1691 (which has been fixed on Github).

Comment: @YihuiXie Installed the development version of `knitr` from GitHub, now `include_url` works fine. I'm using it for teaching and the next lesson is in 2 days, so that's a relief :-) Thanks for your quick reply and for making these fantastic tools!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I probably cannot release a new version to CRAN in 2 days (due to the huge number of reverse dependencies of knitr that I need to check), but probably will do it in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I'm not teaching about `knitr` but web mapping, using `bookdown` to build the HTML book with the course materials - 
http://159.89.13.241:8000/web-mapping/
The book has a lot of iframes with the examples, and the problem was that I couldn't update the book without breaking the iframes. That's perfectly fine that the new version of `knitr` is not on CRAN, I'm now using the development version for building the book. Thanks!